# Invalid useSelector hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I was trying to add my todos in my todo list but when I write something on bar and click the add button I'm getting this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

here is the error code:

```
  2 | import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
  3 | 
  4 | const TodoList = () => {
> 5 |   const list = useSelector((state) => state.todoList);
  6 |   return (
  7 |     <div>
  8 |       <ul>
```

and here is my some of files:

AddTodo.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { addTodo } from "../redux/actions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import { SetValueInput } from "../redux/actions";

function AddTodo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const inputHandler = (text) => {
    setInput(text);
    dispatch(SetValueInput(text));
  };

  // I didn't use this yet.
  const addHandler = () => { 
    dispatch(addTodo(input));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        input={input}
        onChange={(event) => inputHandler(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter here..."
      />
      <button
      type= "submit"
      onClick={TodoList}>Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddTodo;
```

TodoList.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const TodoList = () => {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.todoList);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map((todo) => (
          <ul key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</ul>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

actions.js

```
export const ADD_TODO = "ADD_TODO";
export const SET_VALUE = "SET_VALUE"

let nextTodo = 0;

export const addTodo = text => ({
    type: "ADD_TODO",
    text
})

export const SetValueInput = (t) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_VALUE,
            id:nextTodo++,
            text: [t]
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

reducers.js

```
import {
    SET_VALUE
} from "./actions";
import {
    ADD_TODO
} from "./actions"

let initial_state = [{
    text: ""
}]
export const TodoReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return [{
                text: action.text,
            }]

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const TodoListReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALUE:
            return [{
                ...state,
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text
            }]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { TodoReducer,TodoListReducer } from "./redux/reducers";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todoList: TodoListReducer,
  todos: TodoReducer
});

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import AddTodo from "./components/AddTodo";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
     TODO LIST
      <AddTodo />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
      <button
      type= "submit"
      onClick={TodoList}>Add
      </button>
```

you are using `TodoList` as a callback function here. It is a component, you can only render that like `<TodoList />`